# Assign a computer name to each network interface

Tags: network, mojave

Currently, my computer is connected both the LAN interface and WiFi:

[image]

but traffic is being routed via the LAN.

My router has assigned each an IP address:

[image]

Why is the computer's name (System Preferences > Sharing > Computer Name) being associated with the WiFi (`10.111.222.112`), rather than the LAN (`192.168.1.201`)?  Does it have something to do with the remaining lease time?

Is there a way to create/assign a computer name for each interface?

Answer (score 1):

Names aren’t associated to adapters, it’s the *hostname* of the computer.

Why it’s the WiFi and not the LAN is basically which one got assigned first.

You only have one entry because, well, you can only have one.  Many routers have a mDNS service (usually attached to DHCP) that manages the resolution of host names to IP addresses.  This is a 1-to-1 relationship.  If you had one name pointing to two different IPs, your computer wouldn’t know where to go.

Comment: There isn't a way to assign a `hostname` to a networkinterface?

Comment: Hostname is the name of the *host* which is the computer.  It can have different names of different subnet, but you only have one